# $\int_{0}^{1} t^2 \sqrt{1+4t^2} dt$ plugging in limits assist

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

Solve $\int_{0}^{1} t^2 \sqrt{1+4t^2} dt$

Making the substitution $t=\frac{\sinh(x)}{2},$ then $4t^2=\sinh^2(x),$ and we get $dt=\frac{\cosh(x)}{2}dx$

$$\begin{align}
\int t^2 \sqrt{(1+4t^2)}dt&=\frac{1}{8}\int{\sinh^2(x)}\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(x)}\cosh(x)dx\\
&=\frac{1}{8}\int{\sinh^2(x)}\cosh^2(x)dx=\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{1}{32}\sinh(4x)-4x\right) +C \\
&= \frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{1}{32}(4\sinh(x)\cosh(x) - 8\sinh^3(x)\cosh(x)) - 4x\right) + C\\
&=\left[\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{1}{32}(4(2t)\sqrt{1+4t^2} - 8(2t)^3\sqrt{1+4t^2}) - 4\sinh^{-1}(2t)\right)\right]_{0}^{1} \approx -1.222
\end{align}$$
Answer is like 0.6 not what I have.. where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes.

$$\begin{align}
\int t^2 \sqrt{(1+4t^2)}dt&=\frac{1}{8}\int{\sinh^2(x)}\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(x)}\cosh(x)dx\\
&=\frac{1}{8}\int{\sinh^2(x)}\cosh^2(x)dx=\frac{1}{8\times 32}\left(\sinh(4x)-4x\right) +C \\
&= \frac{1}{256}\left((4\sinh(x)\cosh^3(x) + 4\sinh^3(x)\cosh(x)) - 4x\right) + C\\
&=\left[\frac{1}{256}\left(4(2t)(\sqrt{1+4t^2})^3 + 4(2t)^3\sqrt{1+4t^2} - 4\sinh^{-1}(2t)\right)\right]_{0}^{1} \approx 0.6063
\end{align}$$